# SonarQube 6.7 LTS administration permissions changed

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-ops

We are currently on SonarQube 6.1 instance and are trying to migrate to 6.7 LTS. On the current instance we have several projects on boarded. We've upgraded one of our test environments to 6.7 version by restoring our Production DB onto test environment which gets all of production data onto test environment. Post update we see that all the groups in every project get permissions to view source code, whereas our actual permissions template have view source code enabled only for few groups.

Can someone let us know if this is a known issue and has any kind of workaround. Or is it a bug?

Comment: So they are all public [projects](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+6.4+Upgrade+Notes)?

Comment: No, all the projects on our instance are private. I don't see this behavior in all the projects, it appears in some projects and whereas in some projects it seems to be as expected(see source code enabled only for few groups)

Comment: you're migrating from 6.1 to 6.7 LTS. Which permissions were changed? I haven't heard about similar migration issues on permissions. There are public and private projects now to quality projects.